# JavaScript conserve HTML entities as code when serializing

Tags: javascript, serialization, html-entities

I have the following **HTML**:

```
<p>This contains an HTML space entity &#160;.</p>
```

I need to serialize this HTML to text along with HTML entities as their existing code (spaces added to prevent SO from rendering literal characters):

> < p >This contains an HTML space entity & #160;.< / p >

When serializing the HTML the HTML entities are **rendered** instead of converted to their code/text form:

```
new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(element)
```

I've looked in to other methods of converting HTML code to text including `innerHTML` though I haven't managed to determine any direct means to outputting the HTML code that exists without it being modified by the browser.

I'm also open to replacing HTML entities with a `createTreeWalker` if need be though I'd prefer a more direct approach. No frameworks. Suggestions please?

Comment: I would try grabbing the innerHTML, and escaping the &#160; manually (maybe with a little function that you can find around online), then when it gets outputted, it will unescape naturally and put back what you had there.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3700369/3218479.

You can use code like:

```
// Prepare element
var myEl = document.createElement("p");
myEl.innerText = "This contains an HTML space entity &#160;.";

// Convert to string
var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
textArea.innerHTML = myEl.outerHTML;
var myElText = textArea.innerText;
delete textArea;
```